# How can I convert a OLE Automation Date value to a date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, double

My application stores dates as OLE Automation doubles with the `DateTime.ToOADate()` command.

I need to create a SQL view which shows me the Date stored. How can I quickly convert the double to a date?

Comment: Depending on your use of these columns, I'd be inclined to store them as DATETIMEs rather than doubles.  An index on a double column is useless if you have to explicitly convert the value to a DATETIME for filteration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN OLEFLOAT > 0 THEN 
                         OLEFLOAT-2.0 
                 ELSE 
       2*CAST(OLEFLOAT AS INT) - 2.0 +  ABS(OLEFLOAT) END as datetime)
```

work? From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx)

> An OLE Automation date is implemented
>   as a floating-point number whose
>   integral component is the number of
>   days before or after midnight, 30
>   December 1899, and whose fractional
>   component represents the time on that
>   day divided by 24. For example,
>   midnight, 31 December 1899 is
>   represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January
>   1900 is represented by 2.25; midnight,
>   29 December 1899 is represented by
>   -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.25.

That sounds pretty much like the same system SQL Server uses when you cast a date as a float except the offset needed to be fiddled by 2 and for "negative" dates. SQL server will substract backwards. So -1.25 is 18:00 whereas for OLE that means 06:00.

Comment: yeah, I was dumb and first asked before tryed the cast or convert option.... But now I have another problem. In MS SQL 2005/8 the value 1 represents 2 January of 1900, so all my dates are plus 2 days! Is this normal?

Comment: @Nuno I found that as well. I've adjusted my post. There's another slight wrinkle as well with negative dates. I'll update again in a few minutes.