# Convert Excel Serial Date in Log Parser

Tags: excel, date, logparser

I'm converting Excel serial dates (OA dates) in [Log Parser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx).

I have this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10
  Field1 as ExcelSerialDate, /* days since 1900-01-01 */ 
  to_timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as BaseDate,
  mul(sub(to_real(Field1),2.0),86400.0) as SecondsFromBase,
  add(to_localtime(to_timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')),
  to_timestamp(mul(sub(to_real(Field1),2.0),86400.0))) as Date
FROM 'MyData.txt'
```

where MyData.txt just contains an Excel serial date per line:

```
ExcelSerialDate
42397.6668676968
42397.6663989236
42397.664126875
42397.6668321065
42397.6668733565
42397.6668907523
42397.6668711921
42397.6657181597
42397.666233044
42397.6654758681 ...
```

It gives output

```
ExcelSerialDate BaseDate    SecondsFromBase Date
42397.6668676968    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985617.369  28/01/16 04:00:17 PM
42397.6663989236    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985576.867  28/01/16 03:59:36 PM
42397.664126875 01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985380.562  28/01/16 03:56:20 PM
42397.6668321065    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985614.294  28/01/16 04:00:14 PM
42397.6668733565    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985617.858  28/01/16 04:00:17 PM
42397.6668907523    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985619.361  28/01/16 04:00:19 PM
42397.6668711921    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985617.671  28/01/16 04:00:17 PM
42397.6657181597    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985518.049  28/01/16 03:58:38 PM
42397.666233044 01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985562.535  28/01/16 03:59:22 PM
42397.6654758681    01/01/00 12:00:00 AM    3662985497.115  28/01/16 03:58:17 PM
```

which is correct.

Is this the best way? I have two subtract 2 days from the serial date before creating the timestamp and adding that to the base date of 1900-01-01, and that seems counterintuitive.

Comment: Not familiar with LogParser. But the values in ``MyData.txt` convert to those in your `Date` column under output when formatted, in Excel as a data/time (+/- one second). So I don't know why, in logparser, you need to subtract **two** days, unless it has something to do with a difference in the date assumptions in logparser vs excel.  In Excel, `1/1/1900` = `1` and `29-Feb-1900` is a deliberately introduced valid date.

Comment: In Log Parser SQL, is there a method similar to the `DateTime.FromOADate` Method?  In Power Query, one could use: `DateTime.From` and it would except your ExcelSerialDate (after it is converted to a number).  Although you may want to check [Convert OLE Automation date to date in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277757/how-can-i-convert-a-ole-automation-date-value-to-a-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: Ah, ok, that's a good lead -- thanks. THere's no FromOADate sadly. I didn't realise 1/1/1900 was 1 -- I believed it to be 0. That's a start.